# Windows doesn't want to boot when enablig Intel Smart Response Technology

Tags: windows-7, ssd, raid

I have recently built a new computer and bought a 120GB Corsair Force 3 SSD hard drive with it. I installed it all, and everything was runnig smoothly, but then I decided to try the Intel Smart Response Technoloy, and since, it's been all messed up.

**My configuration**:

- Intel i5 2500k 3.3GHz (not overclocked)
- Gigabyte GA-Z68X-UD3P-B3 motherboard
- MSI GTX 580 Twin Frozr II
- Seagate 2TB Sata 2, I made two partitions with this, 500GB for the OS, the rest for data
- Corsair Force 3 120GB SSD

**Steps taken:**

1. Go to BIOS, enable RAID.
2. Unplug SSD, reboot into Windows 7 setup
3. Install Windows 7 on the 500GB partition
4. Boot into Windows, install driver and reboot
5. Install ISRT and reboot
6. Enable ISRT with default settings
7. Restart

**The problem(s):**
Everything runs fine, until I restart at step 7, there I have gotten different errors. First time round, drivers were found normally durig Windows setup, but after step 7, it was stuck at "Loading Operating System". Then I reinstalled, same way (after doing some more research and folowing tutorials), same thing happened, except this time, I had to load the drivers from a USB, and after step 7, I got the error "BOOTMGR is missing", now I'm trying for the third time, but at first it didn't  want to find any drivers, even with the driver disc, so I rebooted with RAID disabled, and removed he unnecessary partitions, and rebooted into Windows setup wih RAID enabled. This time it found the drives (by loading drivers from USB storage), however, the full SSD shows only 47GB available (no other partition), and I can't select the 500GB partition for windows installation as it says "**Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS settings**"

Note that first time round, Windows 7, with all drivers, was installed on the SSD,  which I formatted during setup.

Any idea what I am doing wrong/may be wrong?

If you need any more information, just ask.

Comment: Did you ever plug the SSD back in? I don't see it clearly listed in your 7 steps.

Answer (score 1):

Hosh,

I can't explain why windows froze at startup the first time round, apart from that maybe partitioning your system drive at this stage may have been a mistake.

I often find it best to do this later, after windows has mucked about with my system during its installation. Just use a partition resizing tool once you've gotten everything else to work.

Changing between RAID, AHCI and IDE in BIOS *post-install*, will cause windows to crash or freeze on boot-up. You must pick a controller option and stick to it. If you change between these options and then change back, you will have to run Startup Repair from your Win7 disc.

The error

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may
>   not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is
>   enabled in the computer's BIOS settings

is most likely due to the controller being set incorrectly, the **"BOOTMGR is missing"**; the result of switching back.

Also, GUI Partition Table partitions will only boot from AHCI, not RAID, so this could be an issue.

I found this out myself through trial and error.

The 47GB RAID volume on the SSD is what remains after the 64GB(maximum) Smart Response cache volume is set up. You will no doubt find that your 128GB Corsair Force 3 shows up as ~111GB, just like my OCZ Nocti does. This can be initialized and formatted as a storage volume or whatever (I'm currently trying in vain to install Ubuntu Linux on this volume on my system by using *dmraid* to detect and mount it, thus giving me a dual-boot system: the RAID volumes are detected, but not the partitions within.)  :(

I hope this helps in some way, even though it doesn't solve your problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Well-written and very informative; even though it's not an "answer" +1 - it'd be too long for a comment anyway